# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/instrumentation/SimpleInstrumentation (GraphQL and Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I am experimenting with GraphQL and Spring Boot, when i try to run one of my GraphQL queries i get the next error: (Graphiql loads fine btw)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/instrumentation/SimpleInstrumentation

POM dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and this is the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/instrumentation/SimpleInstrumentation
at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker$Builder.lambda$new$0(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:101) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker.getInstrumentation(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:72) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker.newGraphQL(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:57) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker.query(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:92) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker.query(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:88) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker.query(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:39) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.query(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:265) [graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.lambda$new$2(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:183) [graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doRequest(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:236) [graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doRequestAsync(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:227) [graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doPost(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:257) [graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ....
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: graphql.execution.instrumentation.SimpleInstrumentation
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you checked if the SimpleInstrumentation class is in one the dependencies and that all dependencies are on the build path?

Comment: Yes i checked, and it was not there. Seems the problem i have is the dependencies are not compatible between them. Need to check if the version are correct. Thanks a lot for commenting, that gave me the clue i needed.

Comment: I think that if you go with the latest versions you should not have compatibility. You should also check that graphql-spring-boot-starter does not include graphql-java-tools, in which case you could face dependency conflicts that you would need to solve by excluding one of the dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `graphql-spring-boot-starter` and `graphql-java-tools` will include `graphql-java` under the hood. Both of them are including different version now .

One includes 6.0 while other includes 9.2. 6.0 is somehow takes effect which is a very old version which `SimpleInstrumentation` is added after this version and hence `NoClassDefFoundError` happens.

The short answer is to upgrade the version of `graphql-spring-boot-starter` and `graphql-java-tools` such that they use the same version of `graphql-java`.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to check which version of `graphql-java` is included.

Comment: Hi!  this solved my problem. I upgraded graphiql-spring-boot-starter to version 5.0.2 to match graphql-spring-boot-starter and that fixed the issue.  Thanks.